# compare Excel file value with multiple spreadsheet

Tags: python, linux, excel

I have Excel sheet which contain more than 20 spreadsheet and Each spreadsheet contain more than 1000 rows. I am generating this Excel sheet using python program in Linux Environment.
But I can also bring these file into windows Environment. is it possible to compare two Excel sheet with spreadsheet data?. Does anyone use any tool in windows,Linux and Excel property or Python to compare spreadsheet sheet with data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree for negative point without google it. Sometime I did this mistake. Thanks a lot for reply. But I have found the following tool which compare two Excel.anyway it is programing . Just FYi If you are looking for such tool.

http://www.florencesoft.com/

Answer (score 1):

VBA is the most obvious solution.
Load the used range of each sheet into an array and loop through the array.
Don't loop through the range, because that will take time.

Some code written on the fly as basic example of how it works. 
There'll be customization for you to do, depending on how and what you want to compare. Anyhow, this is just the general principle.

```
Dim lCnt_A as Long
Dim lCnt_B as Long 
Dim vArray_1 as variant
Dim vArray_2 as variant
Dim oRange_1 as Excel.range 
Dim oRange_2 as Excel.range
Dim lCnt_Rows as Long
Dim lCnt_Cols as Long

'Don't do this: 
for lCnt_A = 1 to 5000 
    for lCnt_B = 1 to 100
        if thisworkbook.sheets(1).cells(lCnt_A, lCnt_B).value <> Thisworkbook.sheets(2).cells(lCnt_A, lCnt_B).value Then 
            Msgbox ("Difference spotted in cell" & thisworkbook.sheets(1).cells(lCnt_A, lCnt_B).Address)
        end if
    next lCnt_B
next lCnt_A


'But rather this, it's faster: 
set oRange_1 = thisworkbook.sheets(1).usedrange 
set oRange_2 = thisworkbook.sheets(2).usedrange
lCnt_Rows = oRange_1.rows.count 
lCnt_Cols = oRange_1.rows.count 

redim vArray_1(1 to lCnt_Rows, 1 to lCnt_Cols)
redim vArray_2(1 to lCnt_Rows, 1 to lCnt_Cols)

vArray_1 = oRange_1
vArray_2 = oRange_2    

for lCnt_A = 1 to 5000 
    for lCnt_B = 1 to 100
        if vArray_1(lCnt_A, lCnt_B) <> vArray_2(lCnt_A, lCnt_B) then
            Msgbox ("Difference spotted in row " & lCnt_A & " and column " & lCnt_B)
        end if
    next lCnt_B
next lCnt_A
```